# Get code model from c++ file checked out from tfs

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-sdk

I'm currently building a checkin policy plugin which performs some static code analysis based on the VCCodeModel code model from the VS sdk.

I can get the code model from an active document in a solution via

```
FileCodeModel fcm = _dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel;
```

But if I check out for example a single .cpp and not the whole solution there is no code model available (because it is not part of a solution?).

Is there any way to get access to the code model from a single file checked out from tfs?

Or is there any workaround like building a temp solution?

How can I access the code model for a file via the filepath/name?

Thanks